# SignalR Hub Authorization for Blazor WebAssembly with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I have set up a SignalR Blazor WebAssembly app with JWT authentication, configured to send the token through query field access_token.

At the server, I see that it is assigning the context.Token from this value.

However, for the hub, annotated with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)], I am getting 401.

Why is it not authorizing?

This is the code for the hub: https://github.com/jonasarcangel/SignalRAuthTest/blob/master/SignalRAuthTest/Server/SignalR/MessagesHub.cs

This is what I have in Startup.cs: https://github.com/jonasarcangel/SignalRAuthTest/blob/master/SignalRAuthTest/Server/Startup.cs

And this is client:
https://github.com/jonasarcangel/SignalRAuthTest/blob/master/SignalRAuthTest/Client/Pages/SignalR.razor.cs

Comment: Have you tried with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific issue it here, but you should switch to using the AccessTokenProvider instead of manually creating the query string.

`var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://example.com/chathub", options =>
    { 
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(_myAccessToken);
    })
    .Build();`

Comment: https://github.com/Cular/SignalRJwtAuthTest/tree/ed0b2913876e90a75e0505f6dece95d10cba9ca1/SignalRAuthTest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works with the WebAssembly self hosted Identity server with [Authorize] attribute on the hub (which uses bearer tokens...).

What is important is configuring of a function to get the token on Hub start. The hub connection can use whatever transport mechanism it needs to send the access token.

```
 hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                {
                    var accessTokenResult = await AccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                    accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
                    return accessToken.Value;
                };
            })
            .Build();
```

The full page I adapted from the 3.1 SignalR tutorials.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@page "/chat"
@attribute [Authorize]
@implements IDisposable

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        User:
        <input @bind="userInput" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string userInput;
    private string messageInput;

    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IAccessTokenProvider AccessTokenProvider { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                {
                    var accessTokenResult = await AccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                    accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
                    return accessToken.Value;
                };
            })
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    Task Send() =>
        hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ = hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is a working [repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/SignalRAuth)

Here are the [changes](https://github.com/BrianLParker/SignalRAuth/commit/7bbf5fdacdc22dc65e42ee2390a6d58eb7bcb14c) I made to the standard WebAssembly with Identity project. Other than the page I posted I basically followed the [WebAssembly Signalr tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

In your solution:
SignalR.razor

```
 hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/messageshub"), options =>
             {
                 options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                 {
                     var accessTokenResult = await tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                     accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
                     return accessToken.Value;
                 };
             })
            .Build();
```

In Startup.cs change this back to the template.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                  .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Then just [Authorize] on your hub.

Your code [working](https://github.com/BrianLParker/SignalRAuthTest)