# Blazor Server-Side with SignalR and Asp.Net Core Identity Feature : Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

Hope all is well.

I' m trying to implement SignalR in my Blazor server-side app, which also implements Asp.net core identity.
I get the following message when I navigate to the razor page that implements the signalr hub:

“**HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).**”

And the following is highlighted in red for exception:

**await hubConnection.StartAsync();**

Here is my razor page code behind:

private HubConnection hubConnection;

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/EmployeePresenceStatusHub"))
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

    hubConnection.On("ReceiveMessage", () =>
    {
        LoadEmployeesPresenceStatus();
        StateHasChanged();//Refresh the component using updated data
    });

    await hubConnection.StartAsync();

}
```

Here is my hub class:

```
public class EmpoyeesPresenceStatusHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage");
    }
}
```

I've followed the example from here:

[Use ASP.NET Core SignalR with Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server)

I'm presuming asp.net core identity feature in my Blazor app is causing this?

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication by any chance?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617648/6152891 Don't use the code... Instead see updated version here: https://github.com/enetstudio/SignalRServerIdentityAuthentication

Answer (score 4):

Try Using Cookies to connect to the hub. I am sure if that is ideal but it solved my issue.

---

**Create a cookie provider class**

```cs
    public class CookieProvider
    {
        public string Cookie { get; set; }
    }
```

---

**Register this class as a Scoped Service**

```cs
    buider.Services.AddScoped<CookieProvider>(); //net6.0
    services.AddScoped<CookieProvider>(); //net5.0
```

---

**Inject the service globaly in _imports.razor**

---

```cs
    @inject CookieProvider CookieProviderService
```

---

**Inside App.razor add a code section with the following**

```cs
   [Parameter]
   public string Cookie { get; set; }
   protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
        CookieProviderService.Cookie = Cookie;

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
   }
```

---

**Inside _Host.cshtml**

```cs
@{
    var cookie = 
        HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];

 }

<component type="typeof(App)" param-Cookie="cookie"  render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

---

**Lastly Create Your Hubconnection**

```cs
 var container = new CookieContainer();
            var cookie = new Cookie()
            {
                Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application",
                Domain = "localhost",
                Value = CookieProviderService.Cookie
            };
            container.Add(cookie);
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(ChatHub.HubUrl),
                             options =>
                             {
                                 options.Cookies = container;
                             })
                            .WithAutomaticReconnect()

                            .Build();
```