# Blazor Server with Signalr - Authenticating user via third-party OAuth

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr, blazor

I am working on a Blazor Server app that authenticates through a third-party OAuth via Spotify.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddSpotify(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = config.Spotify.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = config.Spotify.ClientSecret;
```

The user is able to login and create an account correctly. I have it configured to save the spotify access_token for later use so I can query the spotify API for this user.

ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs

```
await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);
```

Now, In addition to using SignalR via the Blazor Server functionality, I'm also using a SignalR client to connect to my server on the "front end" page for the current user.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapHub<HostHub>("/hubs/host");
});
```

So when the user navigates to the page that needs the server in `Hub.razor`:

```
@inject HubConnectionProvider HubProvider

    public async Task StartHub()
    {
        try
        {
            Hub = HubProvider.GetHostHub();
            Hub.On<TrackStatus>(nameof(ISpotiFollowerContract.SetTrack), SetTrack);
            await Hub.StartAsync();

            await JoinGroupAsync();
...

//HubConnectionProvider.cs
    public HubConnection GetHostHub()
    {
        string baseUrl = _navMan.BaseUri;
        var hubUrl = baseUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/hubs/host";
        return new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(hubUrl, options =>
            {
                //my question lies here
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(_currentUserService.GetAccessToken());
            })
            .Build();
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that even though the user is authenticated for the Blazor app, I can't the authentication to get the user in my `HostHub.cs`:

```
        public async Task JoinGroup(string userId)
        {
            //Name comes through as null, Identity has no claims, etc.
            var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

I've tried providing the `HubConnectionBuilder > options.AccessTokenProvider` a value, but I'm not sure which access code I should be providing. Since I'm authenticating my user through a third-party token, should I be providing the Spotify access_token I store for the user, or should I be generating a token for **MY** app that I send to authenticate my user for the `HostHub` I'm connecting to?

I've tried sending the Spotify access token, and still get no claims on my user. Is there something I need to do to allow my app to authenticate based on this token?  I've tried generating an access token for my application for the already-logged-in user, but haven't found a way to do so. If that's what I need to do, how can I generate this token?

Comment: That's because the hub allows anonymous calls. A Blazor Server app is still a server-side ASP.NET Core app and uses the same mechanisms for authentication. The [Authorize users to access hubs and hub methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorize-users-to-access-hubs-and-hub-methods) section in the docs explains: `By default, all methods in a hub can be called by an unauthenticated user. To require authentication, apply the Authorize attribute to the hub`

Answer (score 0):

I use this with a hub that Authenticates against Identity Server 4 or AzureAD.

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(uri, options => {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = async () => {
            var accessTokenResult = await accessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
            accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken);
            var token = accessToken.Value;
            return token;
        };                    
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
```

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = microsoftAccount.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = microsoftAccount.ClientSecret;
        options.SignInScheme = microsoftAccount.SignInScheme;
    });
```

```
[Authorize]
public class MessageServiceHub : Hub
{
    ...
```

Comment: The important part is the `Authorize` attribute. Without it, no matter what kind of authentication is configured, SignalR will allow unauthenticated access

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And the AccessTokenProvider is a `Func<Task<string>>` that is called after the user is Authenticated.

Comment: @BrianParker what is the implementation of `accessTokenProvider`? This is what I cannot find. I don't want to implement another authentication scheme, my app is designed around spotify and cannot function without it, so I'd like that to be the sole way to authenticate.

Comment: @DLeh This is code that i copied and pasted from a working project. The token I send is from the host project. Ill find a link to a repo give me a few minutes

Comment: @DLeh https://github.com/BrianLParker/SignalRAuth this is self hosted. It does not have the external provider configured but that is not the issue. It could be added and it would still work.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120607/1492496

Comment: it seems like the `IAccessTokenProvider` is in blazor webassembly and i'm using blazor server- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @DLeh Enet has posted several articles on here re getting tokens from blazor-server. Sorry I don't do Blazor server and I missed that in your question.

Comment: @BrianParker i'm not familiar with Enet, could you give me a link to that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Authorize` attribute to the hub.

A Blazor Server app is mostly a server-side ASP.NET Core app and uses the same mechanisms for authentication. SingalR behaves the same way it does for any other ASP.NET Core application. The [Authorize users to access hubs and hub methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorize-users-to-access-hubs-and-hub-methods) section in the [Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz) doc page explains that:

> By default, all methods in a hub can be called by an unauthenticated user. To require authentication, apply the Authorize attribute to the hub

Comment: I added `[Authorize]` to my hub, now on `Hub.StartAsync()` i get a 401 response, so I'm on the right track. Providing `options.AccessTokenProvider` with the spotify OAuth token still gives 401. What access token should I be giving it?

Comment: I injected HttpContextAccessor into my .razor page, i can't find any sign of a current `access_token` within the headers.  this code returns null: `var context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var access = await context.GetTokenAsync("access_token");`

Comment: @DLeh Did you try my code to get the token?? I know it works..  Is your `HubConnection` in a service or .razor page. A common mistake is creating the hubconnection before the client is Authed. If it is in a .razor page add `@attribute [Authorize]` to the top of the page.

Comment: Debugging the .razor page, the httpContext.User is authenticated correctly. adding `@attribute [Authorize]` to razor had no effect. The HubConnection is created in a service that is injected into the .razor page. In that service the user is authenticated, i've checked.