# Notification to specific user and group in .NET Maui using signalR

Tags: signalr, maui, signalr.client

How to send notification to specific user and by group? My only working code is for all of the mobile users.

I was able to send notification from console:

```
await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "Sample notification.");
```

MyHub:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string message)
{
    await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
}
```

Maui Background service:

```
hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
{
    // Display the message in a notification
    BadgeNumber++;
    notification.SetNumber(BadgeNumber);
    notification.SetContentTitle(message);
    StartForeground(myId, notification.Build());
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send SignalR message to a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72336726/send-signalr-message-to-a-specific-user)

Comment: I need an example in maui :( its my first time using signalr and maui

Comment: The code should be the same

Answer (score 0):

In my app the message senders include the group ID in the message. The chat hub pulls the group ID from the message and sends to the requested group:

await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("MessageReceived", message);

Most of the messages go to everyone in the group.  But I do include an ID field in the messages intended for a single recipient, and those messages are simply ignored by everyone else.